# Implementing pipe using shared memory

Tags: c, shared-libraries, pipe, shared-memory

I'm implementing a pipe using shared memory.
I should write and touch only the library, and not the `main()`.

I encountered a problem:

Lets say this is the `main()` of some user who uses my library `shared_memory_pipe.h`:

```
#include "shared_memory_pipe.h"

int main() {
    int fd[2];
    shared_memory_pipe(fd);
    if (fork()) {
        while(1) {}
    }
    shared_memory_close(fd[0]);
    shared_memory_close(fd[1]);
}
```

In this example we see that child closes both of his fd's, but the father is stuck on an infinite loop, and never closes his fd's. In this case my pipe should still exists (compared to a case when all writing fd's are closed, or all reading fd's are closed, or all are closed, so the pipe should die).

As I said before, I write only the library, (`shared_memory_pipe.h`).
So, inside the library, how can I know if a `fork()` has been made?

How can I know that there is another process who has a reading/writing end to my shared memory pipe, so I'll know to close/not close my shared memory pipe?

I heard something about a command who knows that there was a `fork()` or something like that, but I didn't find it and I don't know it.

Thanks ahead!
Please ask if you need more information.

Answer (score 0):

Before any fork the parent can store the result of `getpid()` to a global `pid_t pid_parent`.

Than at a later point in time the process cann test against `pid_parent` using `getpid()` again.

If than `getpid()`'s result is different from `pid_parent` the process is at least one fork() away from the parent.

Comment: I didn't understand,
I don't write the `main()`, I can't do that there. and if I'll do that on the library, then there are some cases when the child might never use any function of the library, so I could never know what his pid

Answer (score 0):

Which part of the code is responsible for closing the fd's?

If it is the user's code then a `fork()` is not your problem. After all, the caller could do an `execve` to a different program (a common use of anonymous pipes) so your library code is now gone from the process, even though the fd's are still open, so there is no way you can handle that.

If you have a library API to close the FDs, then that's all you can do.  An exec'ed program would not call your library anyhow.

Comment: I just edited my question cause I didn't write the `close()` correct, The `main()` should close the shared memory pipe, exactly as a real pipe, after `pipe(fd)`, you should do `close(fd[0])`, `close(fd1[1])`

Comment: @hudac:  OK, so if it is main's responsibility to close the fd's, not the library, then how is that your responsibility when they don't close the fd's correctly?  For example, they could close one fd but not the other.

Comment: That's right, the user can do whatever he wants... The question is: how to track the open fd's ? how can I know for example if all processes closed their writing side of a specific fd ? because if all processes closed their writing side of a specific fd, then, as a normal pipe, I should delete the pipe, Isn't it?

Comment: The pipe will stay open while the fd's are open.  You can't specifically delete an anonymous pipe anyhow.  But I'm confused, what do you mean by "normal pipe", and what is a "shared memory pipe".  Are you using `shmget` etc., or are you using a fifo?

Comment: I can't delete an anonymous pipe, but if I `close()` the write fd in every process, then the pipe will be deleted. By "normal pipe" I meant to `pipe(fd)`, and "shared memory pipe" is my implementation of a pipe with shared memory (`shmget` etc...)

Comment: @hudac: OK, I thought you were using anonymous pipes.  If you are on Linux then you can track open FD's by walking `/proc/$$/fd` (where $$ is the pid), but it isn't pretty.  However, where will you do that, considering the child might not call your code?  Are you running a daemon?