# Execlp How To Printf C Linux

Tags: c, linux, exec

I have a parent and a child. The child executes this code

```
execlp("find", "find", "-name", cmdCommands, "-exec", 
       "stat --format \"%A %s %x %w\" {}", ";", NULL);
```

How can the parent get access to the output of the find command started by execlp?

Comment: Not without a memory sharing pipe or semaphore or generally shared memory.

Comment: i tried to use a pipe but I don`t know where to place the write in child to send the result

Comment: see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14400289/implementing-pipe-using-shared-memory

Comment: I don`t see how this helps me

Comment: Implement a pipe, read the ececlp output into a variable, send it over the pipe, have the parent read it. profit?

Comment: like write(pipe[0],execlp(...),200) then in parent read(pipe[1],c,200)